# jquery tooltip() not showing at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looping through a set of anchor tags and want to set a custom content tooltip that you can click into for each anchor.

However, just adding a simple text to each anchor tooltip content is not showing up at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
// attch is an array of anchor links
c$.each(attch, (i, a) => {
  c$(a).tooltip({
    content: "test"
  });
});
```

Comment: When are your anchors getting created, and when are your tooltips getting created?

Comment: tooltips are added via a content script which is loaded after the page and anchor tags are already there. I can add a tooltip to all anchor tags, but not individual ones.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `content` being part of the tooltip api. Have you tried using the `title` attribute for each `a` tag?

Comment: Check jqueryui - https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content Using the title won't work because the tooltip will have dynamic buttons. I'm just trying to get a custom content tooltip to show up before I add anything dynamic.

Comment: Ok. I'm used to using bootstrap's tooltips.

Comment: Perhaps you could add an example of your markup?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Just need to add the anchor to the items attr of the tooltip.